# How to reset default printer in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I had to delete my default printer in Chrome (which was a Google Cloud Printer).

Now my print dialog in Chrome is stuck:
[image]

It just displays "unknown printer" and the circle of destination runs forever.

I cannot find any settings how to reset this to be able to print again.
The removed printer is not in the Google Chrome settings listed and I am not able to select any other printer.

After a few minutes the window crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution...

open file `Preferences` in the Chrome Folder (in my case `C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome Dev\User Data\Default` normally in `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` search for `printing` > `recentDestinations` and remove the entry in the bracket